# how to export all my configuration to the database?

Tags: magento2

in my case i have some fields in the system configuration **(the route is = 'admin/system_config/edit/section/someconfigpage)** page with their values which I want to save it not just for me in local also when someone did "git clone" for my project, i want him to get the same configuration that I have in my local machine to his local machine.

> is there some export to database or anything i can do , some example will be great and very helpful :)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All configuration are stored in table `core_config_data` in your database. Just use the `mysqldump` command to export it to `*.sql` file and attached it to the project for others.

You can also append few config values into `app/etc/config.php` file in your project. You can add it manually or using magento cli command like:

```
bin/magento config:set --lock-config --scope=stores --scope-code=default web/url/use_store 1
```

That command will add below entry into `app/etc/config.php`:

```
<?php
return [
    'modules' => [
        ...
    ],
    'system' => [
        'stores' => [
            'default' => [
                'web' => [
                    'url' => [
                        'use_store' => '1'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

More info in documentation: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-config-mgmt-set.html#config-cli-config-file

Comment: But some time we don't share the same database version , so it's better to store those configurations in the env.php file or confilg.php in /etc, is that possible ?

Comment: Yes, you talk about that https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-config-mgmt-set.html#config-cli-config-file. You can add the config values into `app/etc/config.php` file but you must remember that value in config.php will always override the value from database.

Comment: so for example i have make some change and configurations into a module from the backend , if i want to export these configs for that module to config.php ,i should run "bin/magento app:config:dump scopes NameofMyModule " or what ?

Comment: To add sth to `config.php` you can use cli command like `bin/magento config:set --lock-env --scope=stores --scope-code=default web/unsecure/base_url http://example3.com` it will add the entry into `app/etc/config.php`, try by yourself. The path like `web/unsecure/base_url` and others you'll find in the `core_config_data` table in database.

Comment: and can specify to export just the config for a module for example 'MyModule'? with the command above